# Get rid of nonexistent options on workspace selection

Tags: eclipse

When prompted to select a workspace on Eclipse, the dropdown is cluttered with things that no longer exist. How can I get rid of these?[image: Workspace selection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open 'Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces'.

This will show you the list of recent workspaces and allow you to remove any you don't want.

You can also set the number of recent workspaces to remember and reset the 'prompt for workspace on startup' flag if it ever gets set.